# SQL Server - Query Session/Idle time out of user?

Tags: sql-server

I need a SQL query/command for Session/Idle time out of users?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does not enforce a session/idle time out.

Connections and sessions are managed by the client application and API, often using a connection pooling mechanism to acquire and release connections as needed.